# Reading standard output from process, always empty

Tags: c#

Running this code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "tool.exe";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Makes tool.exe run, and output some content on standard output. However, if I try to capture the content using:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "tool.exe";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(output);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Then nothing gets outputted, i.e. my variable "output" is always empty.

I've verified that tool.exe indeed outputs to standard output (and not standard error).

Anyone have a clue of what's going on? Starting to feel stupid here, as it seems to be a real text book example...

Comment: It's probably waiting for input.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but if tool.exe is ran without parameters it outputs some content right away (which im trying to capture).

Answer (score 0):

```
p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler
        (
            delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {                   
                using (StreamReader output = p.StandardOutput)
                {
                    retMessage = output.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        );
```

Try this :)

Comment: Thanks! Still no luck though.. There's just not anything coming through.

Comment: is tool.exe a console app? Have you tried to run it in cmd.exe? What is the output?

Comment: Yep, it's a console app (that I included in my project). It prints a couple of strings.

Comment: Try to do the same with an other console app. 4ex with ping.exe. Does it work?