# Get EXE file output using another EXE file

Tags: c#

I have `EXE` file that connect to server and get server output message (int) and this `EXE` file works fine and return the server message.

What i want to do now is to execute the `EXE` file from another `EXE` file  so i created now console application project and running this `EXE` from this project:

```
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "file.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "arg";
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

But from some reason the output is always empty.

Edit:

I have change my `EXE` and instead of return my `int`, now i print it to console application and now from the other `EXE` i can catch the output but still when running this `EXE` how can i catch this output not from visual studio but from command line ?

Comment: did the program write to standard error instead?

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631655/reading-standard-output-from-process-always-empty?rq=1, but it doesn't have any accepted answer, so I can't vote to close as dup of that.

Comment: No i doesn't write to standard error

Comment: Go read this for all the pit-falls of capturing output: http://csharptest.net/321/how-to-use-systemdiagnosticsprocess-correctly/

Comment: heres a guess : redirecting process-output in windows is a _VERY_ complicated thing - one will need several hundred lines of complex code for that (i already did it a few years ago) and even then : it doesnt always work. I highly doubt that the standard-implementaion in c# covers every case, that may be your problem. May try looking for special parameters and force-modes or something

Comment: that edit .... doesnt make any sense, sorry - i literally can not decipher your words